# Mysql Left join with condition on column

Tags: mysql, join

can you help me with sql query?
I have this problem:
I have two tables

"Join" table: Reservation_has_meal

```
+----------------+
| id_reservation |
| id_meal        |
| pieces         |
+----------------+
```

and table with data: Meal

```
+-------------+
| id_meal     |
| name        |
+-------------+
```

Sample data for

```
Meal:
1 | carrot   
2 | potatoe  
3 | cucumber 

Reservation_has_meal
1 | 2 | 5230
1 | 3 | 1203
```

How can I get this result for reservation with id_reservation=1:

```
id_meal | id_Reservation | name      | pcs |
--------------------------------------------
1       | 1              | carrot    | null|
2       | 1              | potatoe   | 5230|
3       | 1              | cucumber  | 1203|
--------------------------------------------
```

And result for id_reservation = 2:

```
id_meal | id_Reservation | name      | pcs |
--------------------------------------------
1       | 2              | carrot    | null|
2       | 2              | potatoe   | null|
3       | 2              | cucumber  | null|
--------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out

for id_reservation = 1

```
select ml.id_meal  as id_meal,id_Reservation,name,pcs  from  Meal as ml
left outer join 
(select IFNULL(id_Reservation,1) as  id_Reservation, pieces as pcs,id_meal from    Reservation_has_meal    where id_reservation=1) rm
on  rm.id_meal  =  ml.id_meal
```

for id_reservation = 2

```
select ml.id_meal  as id_meal,id_Reservation,name,pcs  from  Meal as ml
left outer join 
(select IFNULL(id_Reservation,2) as  id_Reservation, pieces as pcs,id_meal from    Reservation_has_meal    where id_reservation=2) rm
on  rm.id_meal  =  ml.id_meal
```

i.e you require to replace id_reservation value with the value you are using for searching

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Mysql returns warning: 
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'
And in few words, I want to limit the result with id_reservation and at the same time I want to select all results from table Meal.
=> I want to select each row from Meal and left join the pieces from reservation_has_meals where id_reservation has some specific id_reservation.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. But the result is not what I need because the condition at the end of query cause that results contains only rows, where id_reservation exists - so with id 2 I get empty result and with id 1 I get only 2 rows instead of 3.

Comment: Yes, that works with one correction: in inner select we have to select also column id_meal. After this correct I accepted the answer. Thank you.

Comment: to accept answer you have to select right sign and have to up vote it anyways its good practical question.

Comment: I know, please correct the query before a I'll do it:
select ml.id_meal  as id_meal,id_Reservation,name,pcs  from  Meal as ml
left outer join 
(select IFNULL(id_Reservation,2) as  id_Reservation, pieces as pcs, id_meal from    Reservation_has_meal    where id_reservation=2) rm
on  rm.id_meal  =  ml.id_meal

Answer (score 0):

I have some solution, but I don't want to use inner select and if I would have more data in tables the query is very ugly.

`SELECT *, (SELECT pcs FROM Reservation_has_meal WHERE Reservation_has_meal.id_meal = meal.id_meal AND Reservation_has_meal.id_reservation=1)
FROM meal`

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by on `id_reservation` instead of the conditional join.